# Pigeonhole principle problem analysis

Tags: solution-verification, pigeonhole-principle

Prove that if $a$ is a natural number, then there exist two unequal natural numbers $k$ and $l$ for which $a^k-a^l$ is divisible by 10.

THIS IS WHAT I DID TO ANALYZE THE PROBLEM:
(1) For the difference of two numbers $x$ and $y$ to be divisible by 10,their "units digits" must be the same.
(2) I generated a table for some sample values of $a$, $k$, and $l$.  By way of conjecture, I noticed that $a^k-a^l$ is divisible by 10 when $l = k + 4$ for a number of combinations of those variables. 
(3) Substituting $k+4$ for $l$, I factored the original statement into $a^k(1-a^4)$.
(4) Generating a table for (3), I noticed four cases:
(A) $a$ is a multiple 5.  Then $1-a^4$ has a units digit of four and $a^k$ has a unit digits of five.  Multiplying the two always results in a number with a units digit of zero because four is even.
B) $a$ ia  a multiple of 10.  Then $1-a^4$ has a units digit of nine and $a^k$ has a units digit of zero.  Multiplying the two always results in a number with a units digit of zero.
C) $a$ is an odd number not equal to five.  Then $1-a^4$ has a unit digits of zero, so multiplied by any $a^k$ results in a number with a units digit of zero.
D) $a$ is an even number not equal to ten.  Then $1-a^4$ has a units digits of five and $a^k$ is always even because an even number to a power is always even.  Multiplying the two always results in a number with a units digit of zero 
(5) In all cases the result has a units digit of zero, so they are all divisible by 10.  These combinations of $k$ and $l$ map into a function $a^k-a^l$ divisible by ten.

HOWEVER, THE QUESTION IS THIS: Is all this analysis overkill? Does the analysis in anyway have a bearing on determine how many pigeons and how many pigeonholes there are?  The aim of the problem is to use the pigeonhole principle to prove that a function is not injective so $k$ and $l$ can be two different natural numbers.

Comment: It is incredibly overkill.  $a^1,a^2,a^3,\dots,a^{11}$ will each have some remainder when divided by $10$.  There are $10$ possible remainders and $11$ of these numbers.  By pigeonhole principle, two of them have the same remainder.  Subtracting one from the other you have a multiple of ten.

Comment: We don't actually care *which* they were the same remainder... just that we know that we can possibly *find* two that are

Comment: How are you coming up with a total of eleven such numbers?  Wouldn't there be an infinite set of numbers to consider?  I do thank you for commenting on my question! :-)

Comment: oh, of course there are infinitely many, but we only need the first eleven powers of $a$... really, they could have been *any* eleven powers of $a$.  While true, we could probably have gotten away with just five powers of $a$ and used more powerful group theory machinery, the point of the problem was to get practice with pigeonhole principle (as evidenced by the title and tags).  Ten holes (*the different possible remainders*) and more than ten pigeons (*the actual remainders of $a^1,a^2,\dots$*), we can use pigeonhole principle to conclude there is a hole with more than one pigeon